# Unable to drop columns in table

Tags: python, dataframe

Beginner here.

With the help of someone here I was able to extract the second and third Tables on this page (Team Statistics and Team Analytics 5-on-5) that included this last part:

```
for each in comments:
    if 'table' in str(each):
        try:
            tables.append(pd.read_html(each, header=1)[0])
            tables = tables[tables['Rk'].ne('Rk')]
            tables = tables.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 1':'Team'})
        except:
            for table in tables[1:3]:
                print(table)
```

They are standard dataframes but i just can't figure out how drop some columns out of it. I've tried to do this by using df.drop :

```
for each in comments:
    if 'table' in str(each):
        try:
            tables.append(pd.read_html(each, header=1)[0])
            tables = tables[tables['Rk'].ne('Rk')]
            tables = tables.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 1':'Team'})
        except:
            for table in tables[1:3]:
                df = pd.read_table = [1]
                df = df.drop({"AvAge", "GP", "W", "L", "OL", "PTS", "GF", "GA", "SOW", "SOL", "SOS", "PP", "PPO", "PP%", "PPA", "PPOA", "PK%", "SH", "SHA", "PIM/G", "oPIM/G", "S", "SA", "SO"}, 1)
                print(df)
                df = pd.read_table = [2]
                df = df = df.drop({"S%", "SV%", "CF", "CA", "FF", "FA", "xGF", "xGA", "aGF", "aGA", "SCF", "SCA", "HDF", "HDA", "HDGF", "HDGA"}, 1)
                print(df)
```

but I got this answer:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'drop'

It feels like there's a problem with using "df" and "table" but I'm not sure at all. And this is where I'm stuck for the moment.

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No, the problem is with the compound assignment statement.

```py
df = pd.read_table = [1]
print(df)
print(pd.read_table)
```

Output:

```
[1]
[1]
```

This code assigns `[1]` to both `df` and `pd.read_table`. Then the code calls `df.drop()` but `df` is a `list` and `list` does not have a `drop()` method. More troubling is that the code assigns a `list` to the `pd.read_table` callable. I'm uncertain what you're trying to do here, but this is certainly the source of your error.

Comment: My propblem at first came from the fact that the 2 tables I was looking to extract from were in the html but in the comments so I had to use the BeautifulSoup (see second answer here): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66620968/unable-to-extract-tables     That code works but for some kind of reason, I can't figure out how to select just a 4-5 columns within each table, which I should be able to do using df.drop. I'm pretty sure this is easy to fix but I'm blocked for the moment